# Auto Scanning mappers in mybatis-spring

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Our project structure is as follows:

```
- basePkg
 |- pkg1
  |- dao1
   |- mybatis-mappers...
  |- classes...
 |- pkg2
  |- dao2
   |- mybatis-mappers...
  |- classes...
```

Right now, whenever we add a mybatis mapper to any of the dao packages, we have to add a new entry like the following to spring context.xml

```
<bean id="testDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
  <property name="mapperInterface" value="basePkg.pkg1.dao1.testDao" />
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

It's getting cumbersome to keep adding a new entry for every new mapper. An alternative I found was to use `<mybatis:scan \>`. I'm facing two issues with this approach:

- I don't want to give the basePkg directly as it would entail Spring scanning the whole project structure for mappers which would affect performance. This would mean that I would have to have a separate scan element for each `basPkg.dao*` package. Instead, is there a way to use a single scan element and specify all the `dao` subpackages using a regular expression?
- We use two DataSources (MySQL and RedShift). How do I account for this while addressing the first issue listed above?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have to put this:

```
<bean id="testDao" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
  <property name="mapperInterface" value="basePkg.pkg1.dao1.testDao" />
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

libraries used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
   <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
   <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And making sure

1. TestMapper.java interface will have TestMapper.xml
2. or just TestMapper.java with annotations

if the XML files are in src\main\java, then something like below is required:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-resource</id>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-resource</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Hope the above helps.